# How to match array of sub string with array of string using mongo?

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have follwoing collection structure -

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("54c784d71e14acf9ae833f9f"),
    "vms": [
    {
        "name": "ABC",
        "ids": [
            "abc.60a980004270457730244662385a4f69",
            "abc.60a980004270457730244662385a4f6d"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "PQR",
        "ids": [
            "abc.6d867d9c7acd60001aed76eb2c70bd53",
            "abc.60a980004270457730244662385a4f6d"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "XYZ",
        "ids": [
            "abc.600605b00237d91016cdc38f376bd31d",
            "abc.600605b00237d91016cdc38f376cd32f"
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

I have an array which contains substrings of `ids`. here is an array for your reference -

```
myArray = [ "4270457730244662385a4f69","4270457730244662385a4f6d" , "4270457730244662385a4f6b"]
```

I want to find each element of myArray is not present in `ids` as a substring using mongo.

Currently I am able to find single element using `regex` in mongo.
In above example, I want output as:

```
[
    {
    "name": "XYZ",
    "ids": [
        "abc.600605b00237d91016cdc38f376bd31d",
        "abc.600605b00237d91016cdc38f376cd32f"
    ]
    }
]
```

How do I find substring in array using mongo??

Comment: "I want output as: ...", but in your output no substring from `myArray` is present. Precise, what output expect according to example data.

Comment: @stalk by mistake I wrote present instead of not present, check edited question

Comment: Sorry for being as stupid as I clearly am. But it kinda strikes me that your queried string "4270457730244662385a4f69" does not even match your own desired output or the output given by the present answer. And not only by a single document but possibly several. It may also seem reasonable to actually have an explanation as to why this "string match" needs to start in the "middle of the string" and not at the beginning as would be optimal. If I were smart and all that is. Maybe the question could be clearer.

Comment: @Neil - As per my interpretation, yogesh want to find only those names from myArray which are not present in ids.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it using regex. You can match the string for multiple substrings using **or** operator. It is `|` in regex. Search for 'Boolean "or"' on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

MongoDB query using aggregation:

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$vms"},
    {$match: {
        "vms.ids": {$not: /.*(4270457730244662385a4f69|4270457730244662385a4f6d|4270457730244662385a4f6b).*/}}
    }
])
```

Output will be

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54c784d71e14acf9ae833f9f"),
    "vms" : {
        "name" : "XYZ",
        "ids" : [
            "abc.600605b00237d91016cdc38f376bd31d",
            "abc.600605b00237d91016cdc38f376cd32f"
        ]
    }
}
```